# Pod: new protocol file correctly added to the project, but ignored in the import module definition

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I've added a new swift file, with a new protocol to the sources of a private pod. The pod has been deployed, repository and specs repository updated with tagging etc. It all looks good, versioning, in podspecs, repositories, the same tag is used: the correct one.

When I import the pod in a new project, I can see the new source file is correctly added to the project files (in Xcode hierarchy), and if I use the protocol and I `jump to the definition`, Xcode correctly leads me to the correct Swift file in the pods folder.

However, Xcode complains that the protocol doesn't exist, and if I check the pod module, with all headers declarations, I can't find the protocol indeed.

It looks like the file is added to the project, but ignored in the import module definition.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the protocol is not `internal` because you didn't specify an access modifier? It should be `public protocol WhateverProtocol {}`.

Comment: @LordZsolt That was the issue indeed. Damn. Thanks

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Posted it in an answer format also :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, declarations are `internal` by default, meaning they are visible within your framework, but not visible to anyone importing it.

You need to explicitly mark it with `public`:

`public protocol MyPublicProtocol`.